# Como restablecer una contraseña Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, contraseña

Estoy en una aplicacion que sirve para gestionar un poco los trabajadores,

La cosa es que un chico se ha olvidado su contraseña y tampoco puede acceder al CRM,

las contraseñas estan criptadas con **bcrypt()** y no veo la forma de recuperar ese usuario

Que formas tendría de poder acceder a ese usuario y cambiarle la contraseña? Si se la cambio en la bbdd no sirve por que al loguear usa "auth::attempt".. y si le pongo 123456 no sirve..

Gracias, alguna solución¿?

Se podría de alguna forma mostrar la contraseña desencriptada? en algun apartado de la web? ( SE QUE ES INDEBIDO ) pero tengo los permisos y necesito recuperar ese usuario...

Comment: La forma más sencilla es usar php artisan tinker y buscar con el modelo User al usuario que necesitas, luego haces `$user->password = Hash::make('tuclave');` y `$user->save();` y asunto resuelto. Me parece raro que tu aplicación en Laravel no haga uso del sistema de recuperación de contraseña que trae por defecto.

Comment: No he utilizado el Auth de laravel, tengo un registro y login un poco complejos, a eso te referías no?

Comment: Sí, a eso me refiero. Aunque igualmente puedes hacer uso de los Models de Laravel. Si tu situación es muy urgente, pues usa tinker y cambias los valores como te dije y sigues trabajando en mejorar tu módulo para recuperar contraseña.

Comment: Tienes razon, gracias, publica como respuesta y te lo acepto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu situación parece urgente, así que creo que lo más recomendable sería hacer uso de tinker dentro de proyecto para que sigas mejorando el módulo de recuperar contraseña.

Haciendo uso del terminal y accediendo a la carpeta donde esta tu proyecto, haces `php artisan tinker`

Usas tu modelo user y buscas al usuario:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Luego accedes a la propiedad password de tu usuario, la cambias y guardas:

```
$user->password = Hash::make('tunuevaclave');

$user->save();
```

Y eso debería bastarte para cambiar la contraseña y que pueda acceder sin problemas.

Te recomendaría que usaras alguno de los paquetes que Laravel proveé para que fuera más manejable para ti estas cuestiones.

Saludos y espero que te sea de utilidad.